# Which tag? 'nintendo-wii' or 'wii'?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen a couple of questions [tagged `wii`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wii) and some [tagged `nintendo-wii`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-wii). Which one is preferred?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I tagged my question as `wii` because `nintendo-wii` seems a little redundant to me. I know some people refer to the console as the "Nintendo Wii", but I just call it the Wii. `microsoft-xbox360`? `sony-ps3`?

Comment: I have to say that I agree personally.

Comment: Also, shorter is better for tag names.  Think of doing searches on just that tag.  Would you rather type "[wii] wii sports golf tips" or "[nintendo-wii] wii sports golf tips"?  That's a bad example, as Wii is in the search, but the spirit is there: 26 characters vs 35.  For slow typists, that makes a difference.

Answer (score 9):

`[Nintendo™-Wii™-®-©-℗]`

Comment: +1 for a good laugh. :D

Answer (score 1):

In my opnion, we should follow the official name where possible, and practical.

- [wii] (official name)
- [snes] (as [super-nintendo-entertainment-system] is way too long.)
- [nintendo-64]
- [xbox-360] (and not [x360] or [microsoft-xbox-360])
- [playstation-3] (and not [sony-playstation-3])

The only system i have some trouble with is in the Nintendo DS family (more precisely, the Nintendo DSi XL) however, in my opinion, using the official names is still practical here.

- [nintendo-ds] (most common and most general)
- [nintendo-ds-lite] (usually only for hardware questions etc.)
- [nintendo-dsi] (for DSi specific questions)
- [nintendo-dsi-xl] (least common, very specific, also, [dsi-xl] is a bit unreadable)
- [nintendo-3ds] (what does [3ds] mean? multiple 3D?)

Also, in my opinion we should use [gameboy-advance] instead of [gba] to match the [gameboy] which isn't [gb]

Comment: As a site for enthusiasts, I don't think it's necessary to have the `nintendo-` prefix on DS tags.

Comment: I make a case for [sega-master-system] vs. [master-system] vs. [sms]. I'll take the first one.

Comment: I think "nds" is fairly common for the nintendo ds - could we use that?

Comment: 3ds means 3*d*s

Answer (score 0):

Taking Tobias' idea from [his synonym request](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/572/synonym-request-zelda-to-the-legend-of-zelda), is it possible to have alias tags?  This is one feature I'm not clear on with StackExchange.

If it's possible to have alias tags, I think it would be beneficial to have [nintendo-wii] alias to [wii], [360] alias to [xbox-360], and so on.  That way, no matter which way someone types it, they will correctly classify their questions.

Answer (score -1):

I think "gb" and "ps3" and "n64" should be used. We're a gaming site, these are established short forms for the systems.

Comment: That is a bad idea over the long run. Keeping things clear will better help SEO.