# Synonym request: [zelda] to [the-legend-of-zelda]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

*placeholder text to fill in chars*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jeff mentions in the [comments here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-to-tag-use-acronyms-or-not/95#95), tag length limits are never going to change.

This is relevant, because **[the-legend-of-zelda]** is a bad choice of tag to use by itself to refer to the series. Like **[dragon-quest]**, it will be shared with the tag for the first game in the series (and unlike DQ, we can't just append a "1" and be done with it). So the preferable course of action would be to add -series to the end. However, **[the-legend-of-zelda-series]** is 26 characters long - too long.

Either **[zelda]** (which matches [**[mario]**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mario)) or **[zelda-series]** (which matches [**[dragon-quest-series]**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-series)) should function fine. While -series explicitly identifies that the tag refers to the series, Zelda is almost as big a name as Mario so it is very well understood. And like Mario, this shorthand isn't the name of a game in the series, so it is not ambiguous. Whether we move for a trend of using -series at the end for all of these or only the ones that directly conflict with a game title is the topic of a different question. But for this question itself, I recommend using the Zelda shorthand instead of the extended The Legend of Zelda.

Comment: Update for readers in 2022 and beyond - [Tags can now be 35 characters long](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12510/28182), and the tag is now [tag:the-legend-of-zelda]